# Intval() strange behavior - losing accuracy

Tags: php, precision

I've stumbled upon a strange issue with intval() - I need to show 2 numbers after the decimal without rounding the result. So I use intval() in this way:

```
$result = ($data['a'] / $data['b'])*100;
$data['x'] = intval(($result)*100)/100;
```

This way it works fine for almost all results, but it shows some strange behavior - the second digit after the decimal goes down with 1 for some of the results. For example:

```
$data['a'] = 16.58; (float)
$data['b'] = 200; (int)
$result = 8.29;
$data['x'] = 8.28;
```

($data['a'] is always float and ['b'] is always int)

Is there any way to prevent this strange effect and why it is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the better way would be using `bcdiv()`: `bcdiv(2.9999, 1, 2);  // 2.99` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

Comment: Have you tried to look at bcmath lib? http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: Or floor($result*100)/100? Since it seems you want 2 digit fixed width precision?

Comment: floor(), round(), number_format() round the result up or down - they are no go. 
@NielsenMartinsGonçalves - I have not tried this library, tomorrow I will try to add it to the project, but I'm not sure that it will be approved.

Comment: Did you provide actual values of `$data` and `$result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>What about `number_format` instead of `intval`?</s>

`$var = number_format(12.3456, 2, '.', ''); // 12.34`

<s>**EDIT**</s>

```
$var = floor(12.3456 * 100) / 100; // 12.34
```

**EDIT 2**

It's an "hack", but at least it works.

```
$num = 8.294;
$dotPos = strpos((string) $num, '.');
$num = substr((string) $num, 0, $dotPos + 3); // 3 and not 2 because index starts from 0
$num = floatval($num);

echo $num; // 8.29
```

Comment: Apparently also rounds the last digit. Example: number_format(1.5084586466165) = 1,51;

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer, not it should works correctly

Comment: I tried also that, but the result appears the same - floor(8.29 * 100) / 100 = 8.28.

Comment: @YavorP. I edited again my question. Strings are the solution. PS: Obv. it doesn't works for integers because there is not a "point"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what is happening here, but it is rather hard to explain.

floats are represented internally as binary number with exponent.
While 8.29 is a totally accurate number in decimal with exponent, it is not in binary format. There is a small friction, so it is actually sligthly less that 8.29.

You don't see it when printing it, as it gets rounded away by PHP's magic float to string conversion. But if you use intval, this will show.

You can check here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

8.29 decimal = 8.28999996185302734375 in binary (or  1000.01001010001111010111)

**UPDATE**

To get your desrired result in a clean way:

```
$result = ($data['a'] / $data['b'])*100;  //8.28999996185302734375 internally or "8.29" as string
$result = round($result * 100)/100;  //rounded 828.999... rounded to 829 devided by 100 to 8.29
```

**UPDATE 2**

Note that the result is again represented as 8.28999996185302734375 due to the above mentioned limits of binary floats. So in this special case the whole operation is not even needed. But it will in the same time convert cases like 1.234 => 1.23 and 1.235 => 1.24 when represented as strings.

If you want to floor the result (1.235 => 1.23) but still keep 8.28999996185302734375 => 8.29 then you need to

```
$result = ($data['a'] / $data['b'])*100;
$result = floor(round($result1 * 1000)/10)/100;
```

Comment: Sorry, corrected the mistake. It's 16.58/200 = 0,0829 * 100 = 8.29 . This is fine number, but because all the other numbers are like 29.04÷1825.00 = 0.015912329 * 100 = 1.591232877 I use intval() on it too. And that's when the issue appears for 8.28.

Comment: Well this highly depends on what your ultimate goal ist. If you really expect 8.29 here you could convert the division result to a real string before continuing. `$result = (string)($data['a'] / $data['b'])*100;`